# Ubuntu server : no network interface detected

Tags: networking, server

I was having problems with Ubuntu desktop display, so I wanted to try installing Ubuntu server (headless).
During install on a Razer blade laptop, I get the message "no network interface detected". I resume the installation, and when I restart, there is no way to access internet, even a "sudo apt-get update" fails.
I tried with Ubuntu Server 17.10 and also 16.04.03 LTS.

However, installing Ubuntu desktop does not result in the same error, and after installation of Ubuntu desktop on the same laptop, network works out of the box.

Why does server install fail?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which turned out to be that the kernel that was used by the server installation had a different version than the one the kernel modules in the initial ramdisk was compiled against. This was my own mistake, since I had updated the netboot initrd.gz to a point release, but picked vmlinuz.efi from the base release. How to determine if this is your problem too:

Boot the desktop live CD first; use `lshw -c network` to figure out which driver is used for the network, e.g. "e1000e". Then reboot into the server installation. When it complains about missing network, use Alt-F2 to switch to a different console, and run `find /lib/modules -name 'e1000e.ko'` or similar for your driver, and then `insmod /lib/modules/path/to/e1000e.ko`. You should now get messages as for why it won't load.